# assigning a string and array of strings with only one malloc

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, offset

I'm making a webserver in C, and I want to allocate just one chunk of memory for everything (strings and arrays).

My allocation strategy starts with this. and bp is the buffer pointer for searches:

```
char *bp, *buf=malloc(1048576); // allocate 1MB
```

First 64KB will be the max space for the full HTTP request unprocessed (because I'm not dealing with uploaded file requests). The remainder of the 1MB that's allocated will contain each header that hopefully will be easily be accessible.

Now if I programmed the extraction code this way, I'd have no problem:

```
char *httpreq=buf+65536;
int linesize=8192; //size of each line
int httprn=0; // Http request header number. increments for each header found.

char *crlf;
while((crlf=strstr(bp,"\r\n"))){ //loop until no more enters are found
  memmove(httpreq+(httprn*linesize),bp,crlf-bp);
  bp+=2; //move pointer to skip CRLF.
  httprn++;
}
```

But I'd rather program the code this way:

```
int linesize=8192; //size of each line
char *httpreq[linesize]=buf+65536;
int httprn=0;
while((crlf=strstr(bp,"\r\n"))){
  memmove(httpreq[httprn++],bp+=2,crlf-bp); //skip CRLF
}
```

However the C compiler tells me that I have an invalid initializer and its referring to this particular line:

```
char *httpreq[linesize]=buf+65536;
```

is there any way I can use this kind of syntax:

```
httpreq[n]
```

instead of this:

```
httpreq+(linesize*n)
```

to read the HTTP header n without having to use local static memory?

This:

char httpreq[n][n];

would use static memory, but I'd rather use extended memory for string allocation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you define a `struct` for the fixed parts of your memory management, HTTP request and line pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to properly construct the pointers. Here is example of what you want to achieve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINESIZE 8192
int main() {
    char *buf = (char *) malloc(1048576);
    char (*ht)[LINESIZE];

    ht = (char (*)[])( buf + 65536);
    printf("bf %p\n", buf);
    printf("ht[0] %p\n", ht[0] );
    printf("ht[1] %p\n", ht[1] );

    sprintf(ht[0],"%s\n", "This is the first line");
    sprintf(ht[1],"%s\n", "This is the second line");

    printf("%s", ht[0]);
    printf("%s", ht[1]);
}
```

so, the `char (*ht)[LINESIZE]` tells the compiler that `ht` is an array of `char *`, each one `LINESIZE` long.

The `(char (*)[])(buff + 65536)` is casting the calculation of the offset in the type of `ht`.